# "The timestamp column must have valid timestamp entries." error when using `timestamp_split_column_name` arg in `AutoMLTabularTrainingJob.run`

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai

From [the docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform.html#google.cloud.aiplatform.AutoMLTabularTrainingJob.run) it says that

> The value of the key values of the key (the values in the column) must be in RFC 3339 date-time format, where time-offset = “Z” (e.g. 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z)

The dataset that I'm pointing to is a CSV in cloud storage, where the data is in the format suggested by the docs:

```
$ gsutil cat gs://my-data.csv | head | xsv select TS_SPLIT_COL
TS_SPLIT_COL
2021-01-18T00:00:00.00Z
2021-01-18T00:00:00.00Z
2021-01-04T00:00:00.00Z
2021-03-06T00:00:00.00Z
2021-01-15T00:00:00.00Z
2021-02-11T00:00:00.00Z
2021-02-05T00:00:00.00Z
2021-05-20T00:00:00.00Z
2021-01-05T00:00:00.00Z
```

But I receive a `Training pipeline failed with error message: The timestamp column must have valid timestamp entries.` error when I try to run a training job

EDIT: this should hopefully make it more reproducible

data: https://pastebin.com/qEDqvzX6

Code I'm running:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform

PROJECT = "my-project"
DATASET_ID = "dataset-id"  # points to CSV 

aiplatform.init(project=PROJECT)

dataset = aiplatform.TabularDataset(DATASET_ID)

job = aiplatform.AutoMLTabularTrainingJob(
    display_name="so-58454722",
    optimization_prediction_type="classification",
    optimization_objective="maximize-au-roc",
)

model = job.run(
    dataset=dataset,
    model_display_name="so-58454722",
    target_column="Y",
    training_fraction_split=0.8,
    validation_fraction_split=0.1,
    test_fraction_split=0.1,
    timestamp_split_column_name="TS_SPLIT_COL",
)
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you used to run the training? Also if possible and if your data has no PII, can you share a portion of it (You may host it somewhere public)? Just so this could be reproduced by the community.

Comment: Yeah will do, I should be able to reproduce this error on a dummy dataset

Comment: @RiccoD updated with an example and can confirm that I see same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this timestamp format instead:

`2022-03-18T01:23:45.123456+00:00`

It uses `+00:00` instead of `Z` to specify timezone.

This change will eliminate the "The timestamp column must have valid timestamp entries." error

Comment: this didn't work, got a `Training pipeline failed with error message: The time column TS_SPLIT_COL contains 0 distinct values, which is fewer than the minimum: 20.` error

Comment: when I click on the dataset tab, it shows that there are 1000 distinct values

Comment: @dave-edison it seems you encountered a new error when doing the suggested fix. It might be better to open a new question with regards to this error.

Comment: ah actually this works, did not have enough precision. it would be helpful if the docs were updated to tell users the format needed

Comment: Does this timestamp format `2022-03-18T01:23:45.123456+00:00` have a name? Presumably it is not RFC 3339 as the docs claim, but rather some other format?